# npm ERR! code 1 *happens when put command npm install*

Tags: node.js, npm, nft, metaplex

i am noob i just statred this and i have a problem when i write the command 'npm install' i get some errors of differnt types.
Please guys if u can help me quick i have this problem since yesterday.
Thanks.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\Downloads\metaplex-master\js\packages\common
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c run-s clean build
npm ERR! > @oyster/common@0.0.2 clean
npm ERR! > rm -rf dist
npm ERR! 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! npm ERR! Lifecycle script `clean` failed with error:
npm ERR! npm ERR! Error: command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR!   in workspace: @oyster/common@0.0.2
npm ERR! npm ERR!   at location: C:\Users\HP\Downloads\metaplex-master\js\packages\common
npm ERR! ERROR: "clean" exited with 1.
```

the directory of install is this :

```
C:\Users\HP\Downloads\metaplex-master\js>
```

and i am trying to install the modules from **package.json** and this is using the command 'npm install' and i was just following a video on how to launch a solana nft collection using candy machine v2 from metaplex.

Comment: We need more info to answer this question. 
Please edit with: What are you trying to install, where (directory) are you running the npm install command

Comment: ok done sir i did edit the post with the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `yarn` or `yarn install` inside `metaplex/js` (`metaplex-master/js` in ur case) in order to do a correctly install. Read this part of the [docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/getting-started#clone-and-install-metaplex).

Comment: well bro i did what u said and found now new other errors that are a little easier and could actually find answer on google